# How to trace a value of UIWebView.scrollView.contentOffset

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I have a UIWebView in which I set content offset at some point:

```
myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```

It turns out afterwards that this view is scrolled to the bottom of its content. How can I figure out which part of code sets that offset? I miss data breakpoints and watchpoints on it. But how can i do it in actual Xcode?

Comment: This answer to a similar question should work for your problem as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13980286/55358

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 4.5, in the locals window, you can turn out objects to see the member ivars, right-click/control-click on the ivar of interest and hit "Watch " and anything that modifies that ivar in that object will stop execution.  Alternatively, you can add a watchpoint from the debugger console like this,

```
(lldb) watch set variable myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset
```

or

```
(lldb) w s v myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset
```

(shortest unique command name is always valid in command line lldb)

Comment: NB: the number of watchpoints available is limited.  I think it's four word of memory (4 pointers, etc.) on current arm and x86 cpus.

Comment: I tried to set watchpoint on local variable 'i' with: (lldb) watch set variable i but I got on output: invalid command 'watchpoint set'

Comment: I have checked also this link http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html on "setting watchpoints" section, it repeats what you wrote but it doesn't work with my xcode as well

Comment: The way you've described is good for custom classes, but not built in ones. The only ivar that UIWebView consist of is UIWebViewInternal *_internal so I cannot stop execution immediately on the scrollView value change. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Can you find the address of the ivar with an expression like `(lldb) p &myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset`?  If that works, then you can use `watchpoint set expression -x 4 -- &myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset` (where `-x 4` is the size of the ivar in bytes).  I haven't tried this myself but I would expect it to work.

Comment: I have looked into UIWebView definition and it's only ivar is UIWebViewInternal *_internal. To control it's internal scrollview I may use myWebView.scrollView property which is set as public interface, but I cannot see into internal ivars of UIWebView as it has only _internal ivar. I think there should be a way to figure it out somehow anyway.

Comment: Yeah, if you can work it out to an address in memory some way, `watchpoint set expression` will do what you need.  Sorry the debugger can't be more helpful in this case.