# How do I set an lldb watchpoint on a property of self.view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, lldb

I want to trace when something changes the size of self.view. What's the correct format?

```
(lldb) po self.view
(UIView *) $1 = 0x0a8aba20 <UIView: 0xa8aba20; frame = (0 0; 480 864); autoresize = W+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa8aba50>>
(lldb) watch set variable self.view.frame.size.width
error: "self" is a pointer and . was used to attempt to access "view". Did you mean "self->view.frame.size.width"?
(lldb) watch set variable self->view
error: "view" is not a member of "(PlayViewController *) self"
(lldb) watch set variable self->view.frame.size.width
error: "view" is not a member of "(PlayViewController *) self"
```

I've tried the documentation and other lldb watchpoint questions but can't find anything for this specific case.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The view controller references its view from its `_view` instance variable.

The view doesn't store its frame directly.  It just returns its layer's `frame'.

The view references its layer from its `_layer` instance variable.

The layer doesn't store the frame either.  It computes its frame from its `bounds`, `position`, `anchorPoint`, and `transform`.  The size is part of `bounds`.

The layer doesn't store its bounds directly in an instance variable.  Instead, its `layer` instance variable references an instance of a private C++ class, `CA::Layer`.  The member layout of this class is undocumented.

In other words, you can go `self->_view->_layer->layer` to get to the `CA::Layer` instance, but then you're stuck because you don't know where in the `CA::Layer` to find the bounds.

So, trying to use a watchpoint to detect changes to the view's size is rather difficult.

It is easier to put a breakpoint on `-[CALayer setBounds:]`.

#### On the simulator

Remember to use the **layer address** in the breakpoint condition, **not** the view address.

```
(lldb) po self.view
(UIView *) $1 = 0x0a034690 <UIView: 0xa034690; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa034780>>
(lldb) break set -F '-[CALayer setBounds:]' -c '((int*)$esp)[1] == 0xa034780'
Breakpoint created: 2: name = '-[CALayer setBounds:]', locations = 1, resolved = 1
```

When the breakpoint is hit, the `CALayer` instance is referenced by `((int *)$esp)[1]`, and the new bounds is `*(CGRect *)($esp+12)`:

```
(lldb) po ((int*)$esp)[1]
(int) $8 = 167987072 <CALayer:0xa034780; position = CGPoint (384 480); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 768 1004); delegate = <UIView: 0xa034690; frame = (0 -22; 768 1004); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa034780>>; sublayers = (<CALayer: 0xa033010>); backgroundColor = <CGColor 0xa034960> [<CGColorSpace 0xa02b3b0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 1 1 1 1 )>
(lldb) p *(CGRect*)($esp+12)
(CGRect) $9 = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=768, height=960)
(lldb) finish
(lldb) po 0xa034780
(int) $10 = 167987072 <CALayer:0xa034780; position = CGPoint (384 480); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 768 960); delegate = <UIView: 0xa034690; frame = (0 0; 768 960); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa034780>>; sublayers = (<CALayer: 0xa033010>); backgroundColor = <CGColor 0xa034960> [<CGColorSpace 0xa02b3b0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 1 1 1 1 )>
```

#### On the device

Remember to use the **layer address** in the breakpoint condition, **not** the view address.

```
(lldb) po self.view
(UIView *) $0 = 0x1f031a10 <UIView: 0x1f031a10; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f031b00>>
(lldb) break set -F '-[CALayer setBounds:]' -c '$r0 == 0x1f031b00'
Breakpoint created: 2: name = '-[CALayer setBounds:]', locations = 1, resolved = 1
```

When the breakpoint is hit, the `CALayer` instance is referenced by `$r0`, the new X origin is in `$r2`, the new Y origin is in `$r3`, and the new size is `*(CGSize *)$sp`:

```
(lldb) po $r0
(unsigned int) $7 = 520297216 <CALayer:0x1f031b00; position = CGPoint (384 480); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 768 1004); delegate = <UIView: 0x1f031a10; frame = (0 -22; 768 1004); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f031b00>>; sublayers = (<CALayer: 0x1f030840>); backgroundColor = <CGColor 0x1f031ce0> [<CGColorSpace 0x1e530ad0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 1 1 1 1 )>
(lldb) p/f $r2
(unsigned int) $14 = 0
(lldb) p/f $r3
(unsigned int) $15 = 0
(lldb) p *(CGSize *)$sp
(CGSize) $16 = (width=768, height=960)
(lldb) finish
(lldb) po 0x1f031b00
(int) $17 = 520297216 <CALayer:0x1f031b00; position = CGPoint (384 480); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 768 960); delegate = <UIView: 0x1f031a10; frame = (0 0; 768 960); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f031b00>>; sublayers = (<CALayer: 0x1f030840>); backgroundColor = <CGColor 0x1f031ce0> [<CGColorSpace 0x1e530ad0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 1 1 1 1 )>
```

Comment: On ARM64 the registers are `$x0`, `$x2`, etc.

Comment: running on MBP 64-bits with same command `break set -F '-[CALayer setBounds:]' -c '((int*)$esp)[1] == 0x7fe6e3098000'`, I'm getting this error: `Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 5.1: "((int*)$esp)[1] == 0x7fe6e3098000"
Couldn't execute expression:
Supposed to interpret, but failed: Interpreter couldn't read from memory`

Comment: great with the `$rdi`version from JAL (see bellow)

Answer (score 4):

On 64 bit simulators the break command should be:

```
break set -F '-[CALayer setBounds:]' -c '$rdi == 0x...'
```

Comment: That saved me, replace the whole `((int *)$esp)[1]` with `$rdi`,   

then verify with `(lldb) po $rdi`.  

Howerer I didn't found for `(lldb) po *(CGRect*)($rdi+???)`, do you have it?