# Break point setting in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, breakpoints

There is a variable in an `iOS` app of mine, declared like this:

```
let theVar = UIView()
```

In order to fix a bug, I need to understand why this happens:

```
theVar.frame.height == 0.0
```

So I need to set a break point which is going to stop at the right place in the code when the value of *theVar.frame.height* becomes *0.0*.

I usually set break points at a specific line, but here the case is different.

How should I set my break point?

I have already searched the net and tried a few things, but it did not work.
Maybe because I am using a different version of `Xcode`.

For reference my `Xcode` is Version 12.4; and I use `iOS` Version 14.4.2.

Comment: "when the value of theVar.frame.height becomes 0.0" Its height is 0 immediately. When you say `let theVar = UIView()` you have made a view with zero size.

Comment: Yes the view is initially zero size, in the chunk of code in the post. But in reality the height is not zero, I can print it and check (and have done it), only under certain circumstances it becomes 0.0 and this shouldn't happen. Anyway "How to set up a break point to catch this?" is what I want to know.

Comment: I think you need [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13980286/2227743). Please mark it as duplicate if it indeed answers your question.

Comment: @EricAya Good find.

Comment: Actually, I spent a bit of time looking at the Q&A mentioned. That drove me to an almost perfect solution. But I wouldn't consider it as a duplicate, because the problem has not disappeared, I can just make it vanish as soon as it appear. If it was really solved it would not appear at all. It is also possible that I did not know how to take full adantage of the provided information.

Comment: I could see that the problem was happening during a timer function call, but I could not see what in my code was wrong.